# How to fix this doxygen warning

Tags: doxygen

the warning is as below,
"failed to translate characters from US-ASCII to UTF-8: check INPUT_ENCODING"

I am running doxygen over a c++project

New to doxygen and do not know how to proceed.

Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you're using a special character that is not converting correctly.  Are there any non-English words or other likely sources of special characters?

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_encoding